# Visual Studio not rendering image using SDL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, sdl

Whenever I make a SDL program that renders an image and I click debug, it makes a window an everything but doesn't render the images. But if i go to the compiled exe and launch it, it works, any way to fix it or am I going to have to do this everytime?

Comment: Make sure that the image is loaded correctly. The working directory is different if you run the application from Visual Studio.

Comment: Where is the loading directory?

Comment: If you run it alone, it's beside the exe. If you run it from Visual Studio, it's in the project directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where the program loads assets when running from `VS` depends on the `Working Directory` set in `VS`:

1. Right click on your project in VS.
2. Select `Properties`.
3. Under `Configuration Properties`, select `Debugging`.
4. Check what `Working Directory` is. Try setting it to `$(OutDir)` This will set it to where your `.exe` is.
5. If `$(OutDir)` doesn't work, try entering the path to the `.exe` yourself.